# How to load a Kmeans model in Pyspark? I am getting an error while loading

Tags: pyspark, k-means, distributed

I am trying to load a Kmeans model that I saved earlier using the `pyspark.ml.clustering` library.
I am using the following command to load the file:

```
model = KMeansModel.load(sc,"KMeans_15thSept_4000")
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
"File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel.load.
: org.json4s.package$MappingException: Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have saved your model using the pyspark.ml.clustering library and are loading your model using the pyspark.mllib.clustering library. This is bound to throw errors as per this [thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201608.mbox/%3CCABSaYPX7uLHR4dwPLaHHs_MsTbLB95WNxTJGjqLFY7XEWR16vQ@mail.gmail.com%3E). To load the model you have to do the following -

```
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeansModel

model = KMeansModel.load(save_path_to_model)
```